# How to store a bike trainer without packing it back in?

Tags: trainer

I have a Tacx Flux S smart trainer. I am going to be gone for a bit (maybe a fortnight to a month). The bike is mounted on  the trainer. Is there any thing I need to be worried about if I leave it sitting like that for a month? Mildly humid conditions. Is there anything I need to do to ensure there is no damage etc.? House will be locked.

Comment: If it’s any help I leave my bike and trainer in the corner of my living room all the time unless I particularly feel like going out on the bike. Unless where it’s being kept is fairly damp I wouldn’t worry.

Comment: If the place is ventilated, it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

I have my bike on my Tacx Neo 2T the entire winter, never coming off at all. No problems.

You might want to change that "likely" to "will" be locked, but that's not bike specific at least.

Comment: @whatsitsname: Haha. Thanks. Changed likely to will. Thank you for your inputs. :)